# How does one display * when typing a password in a C/C++ command-line tool?

Tags: c++, passwords, getline, cin, command-line-tool

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read a password from std::cin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413445/read-a-password-from-stdcin)
>   [Replace input with “ * ” C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405312/replace-input-with-c)

I'm looking for the C/C++ comparable way of doing `<input type="password" />` for allowing the user to type in their password after a prompt in a command-line tool written in C.

```
string username;
string password;
cout << "Username: ";
getline(cin, username);
cout << "Password: ";
    [<input type="password" />]
getline(cin, password);
```

Comment: Check out the first answer from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786532/c-command-line-password-input).

Comment: Nick S. - I was hoping for something more platform-agnostic. I also wanted *'s and not echo off.